# How to add menuitem or button on Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

Recently I built suitelet script and I want to execute that script clicking menu item.

Let me know how to add menuitem.

Otherwise I want to add button to execute that script.

For instance I want to add button on list of items.
You could be on items list page by Lists/Websites/Items.
There are already Edit View button and New Item button, but I want to add my own button.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a navigation item by going to your Suitelet's Script Deployment record and adding an entry in the *Links* tab.

You can not script very many of the List pages, if any of them, so you won't be able to add your button here. You are able to add buttons to the pages for a single Record.

If you add your Link to the main navigation, that would seem to accomplish what you want as that navigation is available on every page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have some issue.                                          If I'm gonna make navigation item in List/WebSite/ then what can I do?

Comment: I couldn't understand what the centre, section, category mean here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend reading the NetSuite Help documentation on these topics as it is quite detailed. To get started, see the articles entitled "Running a Suitelet in NetSuite" and "Creating Center Links"

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I needed